# is it possible to set a default value for App Tracking Tranparency as .denied in my iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, apptrackingtransparency

I have a requirement wherein one of the apps doesn't need to show App Tracking Transparency Alert as they are not using IDFA's. Is there any possible way from the code to handle this. I just wanted to hide this ATT alert only for this app, but to show this for all other. Is it possible to set tracking Status to .denied somewhere in the coder to make it hide all the time? Is it possible? Please advise

Comment: I doubt that you can pre-seed the response, but if you don't need IDFA why is your app even bothering to call `requestTrackingAuthorization()`?

Comment: Hello @Rudedog , thanks for responding. So, yes we wanted to stop calling requestTrackingAuthorization() method for this particular app. I am not sure how Apple would take it, the app is in process

Comment: If you don't declare the use of the IDFA in the privacy section of the app, they shouldn't bother you. And if something does not suit them and they reject the app, they write to you about what is not clear to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as current iOS SDK offerings, there's no way to set default value for App Tracking Transparency .

As mentioned in the comments, you can simply just avoid calling `requestTrackingAuthorization()` method in your app code, and Apple's review process is fine with that.

Furthermore, you can even avoid linking your app against by removing `AppTrackingTransparency.framework` from Xcode UI under Targets -> General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content.

[image: Xcode framework linking setting]